# How to avoid running one more time using CURSOR in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have used a cursor in MySQL but it always runs one more time then I expect.
Code like this:

```
drop PROCEDURE if exists test_sp;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE test_sp()
BEGIN

DECLARE varid int;
DECLARE varExit_loop BOOLEAN;
DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR
SELECT id 
FROM test;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET varExit_loop = TRUE;

drop table if exists test;

create table test
(id int);
insert into test
values
(1),
(2),
(3);

OPEN cursor_name;
test_loop: LOOP

    FETCH cursor_name INTO varid;
select varid;
    IF varExit_loop THEN
        CLOSE cursor_name;
        LEAVE test_loop;
    END IF;
END LOOP test_loop;

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

After I run the SP, it will return 4 results, 1,2,3 and one more 3.

Is there any way to avoid having one more 3?

Comment: probably should move all code not related to the fetch check to after the fetch check. (In other words, move `select varid;` after `END IF;`)

Comment: what are trying to accomplish with this as a result set (or multiple sets) coming back?

Answer (score 1):

I have moved

```
IF varExit_loop THEN
    CLOSE cursor_name;
    LEAVE test_loop;
END IF;
END LOOP test_loop;
```

right under

```
   FETCH cursor_name INTO varid;
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: That's the correct place for it.  Any later isn't soon enough.